# Send native tokens without running node

Tags: transaction, native-assets, blockfrost

is there any library or proper guide to send custom/native tokens in NodeJS?
i don't want to run full node (cardano-node/cardano-wallet), just want to build and sign a transaction and submit it via Blockfrost's API?
want something like this: https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js/blob/fb9a55fee07927f8d7c8b0a5aa9efd2d3daf6c77/examples/simple-transaction/src/index.ts
but with Native token option. thanks!
p.s: I want to do it in MAINNET if matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use libraries like [lucid](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/tree/main/src/examples) & [mesh](https://mesh.martify.io/).

Comment: hey, thanks for suggesting these. i have already tried Mesh, but I was not really able to use it, because it was more like TS friendly (import style), and I was not able to import "type" in my node js backend, and I did not find any example for this in lucid. mesh's examples: https://mesh.martify.io/apis/transaction/basic

Comment: Regarding _"import style"_, did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/20330802)?

Comment: yeah, didn't work. can't really find a way to convert "import type { ... } from '...'" to require format

Comment: this worked: const { AppWallet, BlockfrostProvider, Asset, Transaction } = require('@martifylabs/mesh');

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Helios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hyperionbt/helios).

Here is a guide to building transactions: https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/building/index.html

The following links will help you define a UTxO containing native assets:

- https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/utxo.html
- https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/txoutput.html
- https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/value.html
- https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/assets.html
- https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/mintingpolicyhash.html

If you're struggling with using ES imports, then you can try the following import style:

```
import("/path/to/helios.js").then( helios=>{
   const tx = new helios.Tx()
   
   ...
})
```

Note: Helios is more low-level than Lucid/Mesh because you need to take care of calling the Blockfrost API yourself.

Comment: Thanks! figured out how to import via mesh tho

Comment: How did you end up doing it? (might be helpful for others who are struggling with the same issue)